# Jquery Change text of a button on click in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change button text from `mark completed` to `completed` in a table for a selected row below is the code I am using but does not set the value to `completed`.

```
$('table :button').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('button').attr('val' , 'Completed');
});
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no attribute called `val`. Use `text()` method like following.

```
$('table :button').click(function(){
    $(this).text('Completed');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the direct approach:

```
$('table :button').click(function(){
 $(this).val('Completed');
});
```

Comment: @amphetamachine Thanks. I think you should have the power to make edits like that yourself, by the way.